# Correctly run a jupyter notebook in a local machine using interpreter on a remote machine

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using pycharm to develop a program on a remote server.
I am able to connect to the remote machine without errors and create a virtual environment. In fact if I run a script helloworld.py the correct environment is being selected.
The problem is when I use a jupyter notebook and run the command `!which python` to get the current python interpreter that I am using, in fact I get `/usr/bin/python` that is the default one and not the virtual environment I created.

I checked the environment I am using from pycharm setting and as you can see from the screenshot it is correct since the path is the one for the virtual environment.
[image]

So what can I do to run the jupyter notebook with the right environment?

Comment: I am in the process of building this right now, so far I have found: remote-kernel (https://pypi.org/project/remote-kernel/) and for docker: dockernel (https://pypi.org/project/dockernel/) I am experimenting with it today and will post an answer if I get it working

Comment: have you installed ipykernel in both the remote and your current environment? `pip install ipykernel` I usually get this problem whenever I have a new environment in conda (I don't use venv)

Comment: @Adji_PA yes, they are installed

Answer (score 0):

## Steps:

1. Locally create environment: `python -m venv venv`
2. Install jupyter
   `pip install jupyter`
3. Install remote-kernel
   `pip install remote-kernel`
4. Add machines:

`python -m remote_kernel install -t user@remote`

### Venv:

To run a specific venv you have to use the kernel command that points to it, for example:

`-k "/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/<env_name>/bin/python3 -m ipykernel`

NB: This works, but notebook shell commands don't use the environment. For example `!which python` still references the base environment.

Answer (score 0):

I resolving the problem in the following way:

1. Connected to a remote server.
2. Activated a needed virtual environment.
3. Ran the following command:

   ```
   nohup jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --port=8888 &
   ```
4. In PyCharm went to "Configure Jupyter server" and on the tab "Configured Server" put "http://<URL or ip of my remote server>:8888" in the URL control.